# How to set pixel value of a cv::Mat1b?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have copied a grayscale image into a `cv::Mat1b`, and I want to loop through each pixel and read and change its value. How can I do that?

My code looks like this :

```
cv::Mat1b newImg;
grayImg.copyTo(newImg);
for (int i = 0; i < grayImg.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; i < grayImg.cols; j++) {
            int pixelValue = static_cast<int>(newImg.at<uchar>(i, j));
            if(pixelValue > thresh)
                newImg.at<int>(i,j) = 0;
            else
                newImg.at<int>(i, j) = 255;         
        }
    }
```

But in the assignments (inside of `if` and `else`), I get the error `Access violation writing location`.

How do I read and write specific pixels correctly?

Thanks !

### Edit

Thanks to @Miki and @Micka, this is how I solved it :

```
for (int i = 0; i < newImg.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < newImg.cols; j++) {
            // read :
            cv::Scalar intensity1 = newImg.at<uchar>(i,j);
            int intensity = intensity1.val[0];
            // write :
            newImg(i, j) = 255;
    }
}
```

Comment: error in second for, should be `j < grayImg.cols; ` . Also `newImg(i,j)`, no need to use `.at<>`

Comment: So to modify a pixel, do I write `newImg(i, j) = 255;` ? It also gives the same error..

Comment: yeah, also for reading it. Have you corrected the `j` in the second for?

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you both so much !

Comment: just do `uchar intensity = newImg(i,j);`

Comment: also, just use `cv::threshold` in this case :D

Answer (score 0):

```
newImg.at<int>(i,j)
```

should be

```
newImg.at<uchar>(i,j)
```

Because cv::Mat1b is of uchar type

Comment: you don't need `.at<>` at all because is of type `Mat1b`. Just to `newImg(i,j)`.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest :

```
cv::Mat1b newImg;
newImg = grayImg > thresh ;
```

or

```
cv::Mat1b newImg;
newImg = grayImg < thresh ;
```

also look at the [OpenCV Tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html#gsc.tab=0) to know how to go through each and every pixel of an image